# How to center chapter title vertically with koma script book?

Tags: koma-script, chapters

I am using the following

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=part]{chapter}
```

to show the chapter in a separate page. I tried

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{
  \vspace*{\fill}
  {
    \fontsize{45}{55}\selectfont
    \chaptername~\thechapter\autodot\enskip
  }
  \vspace*{\fill}
}
```

but the result is not correct, I want "Introduction" to be vertically centered with "Chapter 1", and not separated like what you see in the picture

[image: the chapter title is not vertically centered]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the values of `beforeskip`, `afterskip` and maybe `innerskip`, too:

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  style=part,
  afterskip=\glueexpr 0pt plus 1fil ,
  beforeskip=\glueexpr 0pt plus 1fil + \baselineskip,
  innerskip=20pt
]{chapter}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\chaptername\enskip\thechapter\autodot}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{45}{55}\selectfont}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lmodern}% scalable font
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  style=part,
  afterskip=\glueexpr 0pt plus 1fil ,
  beforeskip=\glueexpr 0pt plus 1fil + \baselineskip,
  innerskip=20pt
]{chapter}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\chaptername\enskip\thechapter\autodot}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{45}{55}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
Text
\end{document}
```

[image]